# Echo output of sha256sum on a CD's files to a text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hash, sha, sha256

I have a CD whose contents I need to hash using sha256sum and I need to store its output to a single text file. How can I do this in a single command? I tried "echo sha256sum * >> shasum.txt" but what it did was it only appended the text sha256sum to all the files in the root folder and not what I really intended for it to do. Help please?

Edit: How can I do this command such that it affects ALL the files in the subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was close. I think you want to do:

```
sha256sum * > shasum.txt
```

Edit:
if you got subfolders, then something like that should work:

```
find myFolder -type f | xargs sha256sum >  shasum.txt
```

or in the folder:

```
find . -type f | xargs sha256sum >  shasum.txt
```

if you want only some files you can filter with `-name`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.wav" | xargs sha256sum >  shasum.txt
```

if you have filenames with newlines or strange things, you can use `-print0`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha256sum >  shasum.txt
```

Comment: This did the trick for the files in the root folder, but I want to include the files in the sub-folders as well. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `find` with `-exec`, but I prefer `xargs`. I have edited my answer.